# Convert Unix Epoch Time to Seconds in SQL or .NET

Tags: .net, sql, time, epoch

First let me thank you all for your help.

What I need is a function that takes in a EPOCH time stamp, like 1452.235687 and converts it to a readable timestamp like '01-01-1970 00:00:00'. More specifically I only need the time not the date.

If at all possible I would prefer a .NET function instead of a SQL stored procedure. However an SQL stored procedure would work fine as well.

Thank you again,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
double EpochSeconds = 1272672608.55;
DateTime time = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddSeconds(EpochSeconds);
Console.WriteLine(time);
```

Prints out:

```
5/1/2010 12:10:08 AM
```

If you just want the time, you can use `time.TimeOfDay`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a DateTime object with the UNIX epoch (1970-01-01) and use the `AddSeconds` method.

PowerShell demo:

```
PS Home:> $e = [datetime]"1970-01-01"
PS Home:> $e.AddSeconds(1452.235687).TimeOfDay

Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 24
Seconds           : 12
Milliseconds      : 236
Ticks             : 14522360000
TotalDays         : 0,016808287037037
TotalHours        : 0,403398888888889
TotalMinutes      : 24,2039333333333
TotalSeconds      : 1452,236
TotalMilliseconds : 1452236
```